# jquery toggle method's animation does't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, toggle

in the shown HTML code i have JQUERY script for toggling elements with "red" and "green" classes. my code toggles them but with no animation! i want toggles them in "slow" mode.
i try it by animation method too, but it doesn't work. 
please help me.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
div{
 position:relative;
 transition:all ease .5s;
 }
#container{
 width:816px;
 padding:0px;
 
 background:black;
 margin:0px auto;
 perspective:600px;
 
 }
.myDiv{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 
 border:2px gray solid;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 padding:0px; 
 
 }
.myDiv:hover{
 
 -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
 background:#666;
 
 }
 #clear{
  clear:both;
  }
 #filters{
  padding:30px 0px;
  color:white;
  } 
 #filters span{
  padding:5px;
  border:2px white solid;
  margin:0px 10px;
  
  
  }
 .red{
  background:red;
  }
 .green{
   background:green;
  } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
    <div id="filters"><span onClick="red()">red</span><span onClick="green()">green</span></div>
        <div class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv red"></div><div  class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv green"></div>
        <div class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv green"></div><div  class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv green"></div>
        <div  class="myDiv green"></div><div class="myDiv green"></div><div class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv red"></div>
        <div class="myDiv green"></div><div class="myDiv green"></div><div class="myDiv red"></div><div class="myDiv red"></div>        
        <div id="clear"></div>

    </div>
    <script>
 function red(){
  var myArray =$(".red");
  myArray.toggle(5000);
  

  }
 function green(){
  var myArray =$(".green");
  myArray.toggle(5000);
 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Animation seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/6mw0zxv7/

Comment: as you see elements toggle in a moment ! i want toggle them by animation

Comment: Correct, that's the `slow` animation. If you want to make it faster or slower use an integer value equal to the number of milliseconds you want the animation to last, eg `toggle(5000);` = 5 seconds

Comment: please show code snippet. i have not any animation. this is my problem

Comment: I did - see the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: i changed the code based on you said

Comment: toggle(5000) i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

First there is no working jquery in your code snippet.

Also you need to write your javascript functions before calling them. Like in the head section. Better to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of adding `onclick` to each individual element, like,

Html,

```
<span id="red">red</span>
```

Jquery,

```
$(function(){
   $('#red').on('click',function(){
       var myArray = $(".red");
       myArray.toggle("slow");
   });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
#container {
  width: 816px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0px auto;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.myDiv {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 2px gray solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.myDiv:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  background: #666;
}
#clear {
  clear: both;
}
#filters {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  color: white;
}
#filters span {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function red() {
    var myArray = $(".red");
    myArray.toggle("slow");
  }

  function green() {
    var myArray = $(".green");
    myArray.toggle("slow");
  }
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="filters"><span onClick="red()">red</span><span onClick="green()">green</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv green"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div class="myDiv red"></div>
  <div id="clear"></div>

</div>
</div
```

Comment: i changed the code based on you said. but i have the same problem yet !